# Invalid operation: Assert - Error in Redshift

Tags: sql, redshift

I am getting an Assert error that I've never seen before within Redshift.

I created a CTE (let's call it `seed`) that joins 6+ tables.
From the CTE, I need to do some aggregations and transformations of data. I do this within another CTE (let's call it `final_table`).

When I try to query `final_table` (for example: `SELECT * FROM final_table`) I get the following error:

```
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   dex < m_num_colflds && dex >= 0 - m_num_colflds:1 dex:16
  query:     xxx
  location:  xxx
  process:   xxx
```

However, if I were to run the same query that is within `final_table` (but not wrap it within a CTE) everything works fine.

This is a problem because I need to join two CTE's since the specific aggregations cannot be done in a single query.

I am using DBeaver and Redshift. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have virtually the same error.  Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

bit late to the party but i was having a similar issue and just changed my CTEs to temp tables and it worked...